# Defining IP Address for catastrophic DNS Failures - ILO / Lights Out Management

Tags: domain-name-system, firmware

When a new server is plugged into a DHCP / dynamic network then it will  get an IP.  But I want to be sure that I can access this if the DNS goes down.  ***Therefore I would assume I need to setup as a static IP right?***

I would think that the ideal setup for lights out is to define the IP address and hostname:

1. on DNS to handle normal operations
2. hard coded through settings on Lights out interface

I am trying to prepare for a "Bad Day" for example:

1. DNS is down
2. remote access is available to a device in the datacenter where a user can login to local machine and access lights out (IDRAC or ILO) through a local machine.

Comment: Do you know what is static IP?

Comment: And one more point: why did you assign dynamic IP to server?

Comment: Your description looks confusing. On one hand, you are referring to DHCP and then on DNS. Are you sure your questions has the correct terms?

Answer (score 3):

If DNS is down then it doesn't matter if the ip address is dynamic or static. If you try to query the DNS name it will fail.

The solution is to keep track of the ip address that's assigned and use that to connect in the event that DNS is down.

Whether you assign a dynamic or static ip address is immaterial, and is up to you.